# Can SQL Server (2008R2) optimise Sybase Join Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

As outlined in MSDN,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122(v=vs.100).aspx

Sybase join syntax is deemed to be deprecated

i.e.

```
SELECT [T2].[c3], [T1].[c3] 
FROM [dbo].[T2] T2, [dbo].[T1] T1 
WHERE [T2].[ID] = [T1].[ID]
```

however the information is sketchy as to whether the SQL engine is able to optimise this or not.

i would imagine the above example would be ok but what about in the example of more than 10 tables being involved.

how well does the SQL Query engine optimise these queries vs using inner and outer joins?

Comment: This is equivalent to an `inner join` and SQL Server will optimize.  That is a really, really bad reason to use such syntax.  Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: The only deprecated syntax is the proprietary outer join syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SQL Server can optimize it. I ran both on my SQL Server 2012 instance, and it gave me the same Execution Plan for both queries:

```
SELECT [T2].[c3], [T1].[c3] 
FROM [dbo].[T2] T2, [dbo].[T1] T1 
WHERE [T2].[ID] = [T1].[ID]
```

and

```
SELECT [T2].[c3], [T1].[c3] 
FROM [dbo].[T2] T2
INNER JOIN [dbo].[T1] T1 ON [T2].[ID] = [T1].[ID]
```

SQL Server 2012 essentially has the same Query Optimizer as 2008. SQL Server 2014 has a new one, but I suspect it won't make a difference in this case.